# call return from child frame

Tags: r, return, eval, r-environment

How can I return a value in a function, through another function, see example here :

```
first_try <- function() eval(return(1),parent.frame())
second_try <- function() source(textConnection("return(2)"),parent.frame())

fun1 <- function(x){
  first_try()
  second_try()
  3
}

fun1()
# [1] 3
```

`fun1` should stop at `first_try` and return `1`, and if `second_try` had worked it would have returned `2`.

Is such a thing possible ?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand the question correctly. If you want to return at `first_try`, why do you need `second_try` and the `3`. If the return value depends on something else, why not use `if-else`?

Comment: `3` is just there to show that neither `first_try` nor `second_try` work. In practice this function will be wrapped into a condition, so there'll be code afterwards, abbreviated into `3` here. Is it clearer this way ?

Comment: If so, why not try `if(a){return(1)}else if(b){return(2)}; 3;`?

Comment: It's a matter of readability, programming convenience, and curiosity, I'm not stuck in my work. I have a function that will always be followed or embedded by a return call, so it makes sense to me to put the return call inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rlang::return_from()` provides this functionality :

```r
return_a <- function() rlang::return_from(parent.frame(),"a")

fun <- function(){
  return_a()
  "b"
}
fun()
#> [1] "a"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

We can also fix my first try by quoting `return(1)` and use `rlang::eval_bare()`rather than `base::eval()`

From the doc :

> eval_bare() is a lower-level version of function base::eval().
>   Technically, it is a simple wrapper around the C function Rf_eval().
>   You generally don't need to use eval_bare() instead of eval(). Its
>   main advantage is that it handles stack-sensitive (calls such as
>   return(), on.exit() or parent.frame()) more consistently when you pass
>   an enviroment of a frame on the call stack.

```r
first_try <- function() rlang::eval_bare(quote(return(1)),parent.frame())
fun1 <- function(x){
  first_try()
  second_try()
  3
}

fun1()
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>